# Unknown Property on Controller Extension

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, controller-extension, standardcontroller

So I have a standard controller and an extension that I'm trying to use to call back a list from a different object to use in a PageBlockTable.  In the visualforce page I declare my standard controller and extension:

```
<apex:page standardController="APM__c" extensions="APM_OpenChart" recordSetVar="apps">
```

Later on in my PageBlockTable I'm trying to pass the list from the extension using this class:

```
public with sharing class APM_OpenChart {

    public APM_OpenChart(ApexPages.StandardSetController stdController) {}

    public List<APM__c> spoofgrid(){
         List<APM__c> results = database.query('SELECT Name , BV_Result__c ,TV_Result__c FROM APM__c Limit 1');
        return results;
    }
}
```

However, when I attempt to pass the values I get an *unknown property* error when trying to use the list from the extension.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!APM_OpenChart.spoofgrid}" var="token">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change you method to `getspoofgrid`. Add get so it will be accessible in page

```
public List<APM__c> getspoofgrid(){
         List<APM__c> results = database.query('SELECT Name , BV_Result__c ,TV_Result__c FROM APM__c Limit 1');
        return results;
    }
```

And in VF

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!spoofgrid}" var="token">
```

Comment: really?!?!  It worked.  do all getter's need to start with get?

Comment: @tjcinnamon yes that needs to be start with get..

Answer (score 4):

Your properties need a `getter` to be defined. While the approach mentioned by @Ratan will work, you can also "lazy load" your results in a way that does not consume a new query every time. [Here](http://www.forcetree.com/2009/07/getter-and-setter-methods-what-are-they.html) is a discussion on how these methods work.

Alternative `getter`/`setter` patterns:

```
public List<APM__c> spoofGrid { get; private set; }
public List<APM__c> spoofGrid
{
    get
    {
        // run query every time
        // don't need a setter
    }
}
public List<APM__c> getSpoofGrid()
{
    // this is identical (in VF) to the above
}
```

Lazy Load:

```
public List<APM__c> spoofGrid
{
    get
    {
        if (spoofGrid == null)
        {
            spoofGrid = Database.query(someSoql);
        }
        return spoofGrid;
    }
    private set;
}
```

You need a `setter` (which should be `private`) if you want to lazy load because you need to cache the results in your property.

Comment: I think I need a query every time because i need at least 1 record to return to "spoof" the pageblocktable.  Or is that not the case?

Comment: Only if the data is changing between interactions, which seems unlikely.